# AutoIncrement Identity Problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Using SQL Server.

### Table1

```
RecordNo   ID
---------------
2          001
3          002
4         003
....
```

RecordNo column is the Identity column for Table1

### Problem

The `RecordNo` column sometimes starting from 0, some times starting from 2.  How to avoid this problem -- RecordNo Column should always start from 1.  It should not start from other numbers.

```
RecordNo   ID
--------------    
1          001
2          002
3          003
....
```

Need query Help

Comment: How do you insert the data? As Nathan mentioned, SQL server omits identity values for uncommitted record ... but it will never start with 0 unless you tell him!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The auto-incremented identity number increments whether the record is ultimately committed or not. It looks to me like possibly the initial insert is failing or is inside a transaction which is not being committed.

The identity column type is meant to be a surrogate identifier, and it's not recommended to use that number for anything else. It is possible to build your own autoincrement functionality, but that's generally a bad idea because of performance and concurrency problems.

Also, it is possible to [reseed the identity column back to 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) thusly:

```
dbcc checkident (table1, reseed, 1)
```

---

Edit: I assume you have your table definition set properly with Seed set to 1 and increment set to 1 as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the start value when you create the table:

```
Create Table Table1
    (
    RecordNo int not null Identity(1,1)
    , Id char(3) ...
    )
```

[IDENTITY [ (seed ,increment ) ]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

If you need to reseed a given table then see [DBCC CHECKIDENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057%28SQL.90%29.aspx).